# navigating bar item icon not showing correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, image, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem

navigation bar item icon colour blue or single colour. Not able to render the original image in the navigation bar. already tried the option render as original from the Assets.xcassets attributes inspector

want to use this[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO3rC.png)

but sadly when tried selecting through storyboard it shows it in only one single colour square i.e only blue , white or any other colour. how can i use the original image for bar button item.

Comment: Can you please clear your question ? What you want ?

Comment: i want to use the image for bar button icon in navigation bar, but i not able to use it as original. the image is getting coloured from navigation bar tint.

Comment: you can try with below code

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you want to set image on navigation bar right ?
Hope below code will wok for you,

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageName.png"];
myImage = [myImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIBarButtonItem *searchButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:myImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(menuObject:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = searchButton;
```

Comment: i wanted to use to do this through storyboard. and i already have clicked the option to render the image as original through the Assets.xcassets file.

Comment: However this is a good tips. I did it in storyboard and change the image through outlet to alternate between options. After spending a lot of time, now I find that I must set the image rendered as original, otherwise bar button item image took the light color image (not my dark image).

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

This one works for me...

```
UIButton *btnChat = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
[btnChat setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chat_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnChat addTarget:self action:@selector(chatButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btnChat];
```